# Is it possible to create local folder in real ios device?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create local folder in real ios device and save some pdf file on that folder from the application.

Is it possible to save file in real device from application.

Comment: You can use [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) to save a file to any location supported by the "files"app

Comment: Gereon's answer is exactly correct, but clearly did not meet your intention. You should reword this question to make it clearer what your requirements are so that future searchers will know whether this question applies to them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but there are several things you *may* be asking for:

1. Can I put my files on the iPhone home screen, like apps? No.
2. Can I put my files in the Files app? Yes, the sharing API lets you do that, as should UIDocumentPicker.
3. Can I put my files in iCloud, so a user gets them on all their devices and they are restored when they install my app on a new device, or reinstall my app after having deleted it? Yes, look at the iCloud documentation and WWDC videos for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible, e.g. to create a subdirectoy in you app's "Documents Directory", you would to something like this:

```
NSArray<NSString*>* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* yourDir = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"your_directory_name"];

NSError* error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:yourDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i do not want to store in document directory... i want to store it on ios device like if application is deleted from the device but pdf file in ios device should store.

Comment: The Documents directory *is* on the device. But what you want is impossible. You only have access to the app's sandbox directories, which are all completely deleted when the user removes the app from the phone.